# how to add endpoint to graphql client?

Tags: java, graphql, aws-appsync

I want to create a client to consume a GraphQL endpoint.

I've tried the example code provided by [GraphQL
Java](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/execution/), which looks
like this:

```java
GraphQLObjectType fooType = newObject()
    .name("Foo")
    .field(newFieldDefinition()
        .name("bar")
        .type(GraphQLString))
    .build();

GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
    .query(fooType)
    .build();
GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema)
    .build();

ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
    .query("query { hero { name } }")
    .build();

ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(executionInput);

Object data = executionResult.getData();
List<GraphQLError> errors = executionResult.getErrors();
```

I dont know if this its the best way. I'm using AWS AppSync as the GraphQL
server. How can I update my code, so that it makes reference to the AWS
endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Apollo client. Please see this [Getting Started guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-java/).

You will need to do two things in order to use the Apollo client with AWS AppSync:

1. Provide the URL of your endpoint;
2. Add an authorization/API key header to your requests.

Example:

```java
String url = "https://xxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql";
OkHttpClient okhttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request requestWithAuth = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("X-API-Key", "da2-alphanum-string-here")
            .build();
        chain.proceed(requestWithAuth);
    })
    .build();
ApolloClient apollo = ApolloClient.builder()
    .serverUrl(url)
    .okHttpClient(okhttp)
    .build();
```